# How to add new columns to a dataframe if common variables are found in multiple other dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame similar to the one below.

```
df1 <-
Class    Race    Level

Paladin  Human   4
Fighter  Elf     5
Wizard   Gnome   3
Rouge    Elf     4
```

I would like to add columns to this data frame based on the information found in the following three data frames.

```
Mission1 <-

Class    Exp 

Paladin  80
Fighter  70 
Cleric   100
Wizard   80

Mission2 <-

Class    Exp

Cleric   200
Fighter  220
Wizard   190

Boss1 <-

Class    Exp

Wizard   500
Paladin  520
Cleric   490
Druid    500
```

I would like to add a 1 or 0 to df1 if the df1$Class column matches the $Class column of the other three. I would like to add a 1 or 0 for each of the three other data frames and sum up the mission, and mission+boss scores. So the output would look like this.

```
df2$Missions  = Mission1 + Mission2

df2$Final = Mission1 + Mission2 + Boss1
```

```
df2 <-

Class    Race    Level   Mission1   Mission2  Missions   Boss1   Final

Paladin  Human   4       1          0         1          1       2 
Fighter  Elf     5       1          1         2          0       2
Wizard   Gnome   3       1          1         2          1       3
Rouge    Elf     4       0          0         0          0       0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `dplyr`:

```
df2 %>% mutate(Mission1 = as.integer(Class %in% Mission1$Class))
    %>% mutate(Mission2 = as.integer(Class %in% Mission2$Class))

df2 %>% mutate(Missions = Mission1 + Mission2)
df2 %>% mutate(Boss1 = as.integer(Class %in% Boss1$Class))
df2 %>% mutate(Final = Missions+Boss1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works. Had to edit it slightly:

df1 %>%  mutate(Mission1 = as.integer(Class %in% Mission1$Class)) -> df2
df2 %>%  mutate(Mission2 = as.integer(Class %in% Mission2$Class)) -> df3

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use dplyr left_join and then change to 0s and 1s based on values being present or not:

```
df1 <- left_join(df1, Mission1)
names(df1)[4] <- "Mission1"
df1 <- left_join(df1, Mission2)
names(df1)[5] <- "Mission2"

df1$Mission1 <- ifelse(is.na(df1$Mission1), 0, 1)
df1$Mission2 <- ifelse(is.na(df1$Mission2), 0, 1)
```